# Filling in Null Value with Another Value in the same Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I wanted to update my column which has null value to fill in using value that has already existed in the table. The null property address can be filled in by other rows which has the same parcel id. I did the query and the result shows in the coalesce column.

Now, I want the coalesce column to fill in property address column.

```
parcelid            propertyaddress      parcelid_1        propertyaddress_1                                   coalesce
025 07 0 031.00 None                 025 07 0 031.00    410 ROSEHILL CT, GOODLETTSVILLE            410 ROSEHILL CT, GOODLETTSVILLE
026 01 0 069.00 None                 026 01 0 069.00    141 TWO MILE PIKE, GOODLETTSVILLE              141 TWO MILE PIKE, GOODLETTSVILLE
026 05 0 017.00 None                 026 05 0 017.00    208 EAST AVE, GOODLETTSVILLE               208 EAST AVE, GOODLETTSVILLE
```

I have tried this query, but it only works on microsoft sql studio. It doesnt work on psql. I cant seem to make it work.

```
Update a
SET PropertyAddress = COLEASE(a.PropertyAddress,b.PropertyAddress)
From PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing a
JOIN PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing b
    on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
    AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID 
Where a.PropertyAddress is null
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How to fix what exactly? Why are you using coalesce, your criteria is where `a.propertyAddress is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in postgresql syntax is like this and coalesce seems unnecessary since you are checking property address null-ability:

```
UPDATE PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing a 
SET PropertyAddress = b.PropertyAddress
FROM PortfolioProject.dbo.NashvilleHousing b
WHERE a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
AND a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID 
AND a.PropertyAddress is null
```